# memrchr give some garbage value

Tags: c

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<string.h>
  3 
  4 int main(void)
  5 {
  6         char p[] = "I'm shia";
  7         printf("%p\n",p);
  8         printf("%d\n",memrchr(p+3,'s',strlen(p)));
  9         printf("%p\n",memchr(p,'i',strlen(p)));
 10         return 0;
 11 }
```

---

Output:

```
0x7fff0eeae950
0xeeae954  /*garbage value?*/
0x7fff0eeae956
```

why does `memrchr` return the value exceed the boundary of array `p` ,`memchr` worked fine.
If such action is deliberate,why?

Comment: Are you deliberately using `%d` instead of `%p` in your line 8?

Comment: @Amadan Yes,When I use `%p` it will generate waning by gcc

Comment: @ZhangYuan `typecast` return type of memrchr to `(void *)` to avoid warning about `%p`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not `memrchr` *vs* `memchr`. You are calling it like this:

```
memrchr(p+3,'s',strlen(p));
```

which says search for `'s'` in the string that starts at `p+3` and is `strlen(p)` characters long. So `memrchr` is doing what you have asked for, and its looking at the *null-terminator* and the two other values outside of your string. You should instead call it like this:

```
memrchr(p+3,'s',strlen(p+3));
```

or even:

```
memrchr(p+3,'s',strlen(p)-3);
```

Comment: `strlen(p+3)` is not correct as it causes buffer overflows. Always use `strlen(p)-3`

Comment: @Manav: How would it cause a buffer overflow? `strlen(p+3)` is fine as long as the string has at least 3 chars, but otherwise both calls would be wrong

Answer (score 2):

Made a couple of changes, but this not code you want to use in production.  It is okay to see how memrchr works.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

 int main(void)
 {
         char p[] = "I'm shia";
         printf("%p\n",p);
         printf("%s\n",(char *)memrchr(p+3,'s',strlen(p) - 3));
         printf("%p\n", memchr(p,'i',strlen(p)));
         return 0;
 }
```

Output on my cygwin 1.7:

```
$ ./memrchr
0x28ac57
shia
0x28ac5d
```